# Retrieve lost file

Tags: usb

I lost my USB and it has some work I did not back up it was orally done on PowerPoint and appears on recently open is there any way I could open it/see it on with out the USB. Maybe there is an copy saved the hard drive

Comment: If you only opened the file from your flash drive then there isn't a local copy you can open

Answer (score 1):

Search your HDD and see.

If the "recently opened" link is to the lost USB device, you will not be able to retrieve it by following that link.

Comment: Search for deleted files too, maybe there's a temporary file that hasn't been overwritten yet